# The x and y axis scaling in Contour plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, contour, aspect-ratio

When I make a contour plot with Python, I have been using a `set_aspect` function. Because this allows me to avoid image/contour-lines distortion caused by changing both axis.

: for example, `ax1.set_aspect('equal', 'box-forced')`

**But, I just found that the option 'box-forced' is not valid in Python3.**

So my question is, is there any alternative of the 'box-forced' option in Python3? I want exactly the same effect as the `ax1.set_aspect('equal', 'box-forced')` in Python2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that there is a function `plt.axis('scaled')`.
It seems that this does what I wanted in a recent version (3.7) of Python3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one from the official documentation that I found in as my first recommended page:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here exactly, but you could try the following:
`ax1.set_aspect(aspect='equal', adjustable='box')`

You could also check the following link which is for the `set_adjustable` method:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_anchor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_anchor

Hope this helps. Good luck!